# Encrypt text using a key having 48 bytes?

Tags: apex, encryption

We want to encrypt a text in Apex using provided key having 48 bytes.

```
Text = 'some xml';

Key = 'TEXT_KEY_REMOVED';
```

How can we encrypt the text using the provided key? Salesforce supports AES128, AES192, AES256 algorithms for 16, 24, or 32 bytes respectively. But the private key which I have has 48 bytes and there is no equivalent algorithm in Salesforce for 48 bytes key. Would you please suggest me any workaround?

Comment: You need to find out exactly how the encryption is implemented on the other side of this integration. The key you provided (which I edited out; never include secret values here!) appears to be plain text rather than a hexadecimal representation. This makes me think it's likely being hashed to a different key size. AES is only defined for 128, 192, and 256-bit keys.

Comment: @David, Thanks, The key which I mentioned is not the genuine. The other side of the integration system will use 3DES to decrypt. Does salesfroce support 3DES? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce does not support 3DES. The only supported encryption algorithms in the Apex [`Crypto`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) class are AES128, AES192, or AES256. An exception will be thrown if any algorithm value other than those three is provided.